# Spring not able to instantiate bean with @Resource

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, resources, inversion-of-control, javabeans

I am running this small piece of code.

```
public class TestIOC {

@Resource
University university;

public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    ApplicationContext context =
        new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("service.xml");
    TestIOC ioc = new TestIOC();
    //ioc.university = (University)context.getBean("university");
    System.out.println(ioc.university);
}
}
```

And this is my service.xml file.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<bean id="university" class="com.test.beans.University">
    <constructor-arg type = "int" value="1"   />
    <constructor-arg type = "java.lang.String" value="Some University"   />
    <constructor-arg type = "java.lang.String" value="Some City"   />

</bean>
```

If I commented context.getBean("university"); I am not able to print the values of university. but with context.getBean("university"); I am able to print output.

I am using @Resource but still I required getBean method to inject the bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `TestIOC` is not managed by spring. If you want `@Resource` to work then you need to create a bean for `TestIOC` and use it.

Add the following bean to service.xml

```
<bean id="testIOC" class="TestIOC"></bean>
```

Then in java use it like

```
TestIOC ioc = context.getBean(TestIOC.class);
System.out.println(ioc.university);
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely because that You didn't config TestIOC class in Spring context, so The Spring can do nothing about it. You should add it as a bean to service.xml. And one thing which is not related with this question I want to mention is that if you use `<Context:annotation-config>` and use `@Resource` to inject the bean, then the bean must be config in the xml not annotated bean with Component. Sometimes it is confused with `<context:component-scan/>`

Answer (score 0):

### @Resorce

```
Indicates that a method or field should be injected with a 
named resource (by default, another bean).
```

In your case, Spring will attempt to wire the “university”
property with a reference to a bean whose ID is “university”.